# Least square with rectangular function

Tags: least-squares, curve-fitting

I have the function $c(t) = A \cdot \cos \left(\dfrac{2\pi}{\tau} \cdot t + \phi \right) $
which is used to define
$ T(t) =
 \begin{cases}
  M + c(t), & c(t) > 0 \\
  M, &c(t) \leq 0.
 \end{cases}
$

$T(t)$ is used to fit in the least square sense to measurements $y(t)$. Now, the question is how to get the partial derivative of this piece wise defined function?

The function is not continuous, therefore I thought to approximate the rect function through a Fourier series in order to calculate the derivative required by the least square procedure:

$
f(t_i, \gamma) = M + \left[ \dfrac{4h}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{\dfrac{\sin \left( (2k-1)w(t+\Delta t) \right)}{2k-1}} \right] \cdot A \cdot \cos (\omega t+\phi)
$
$
f(t_i, \gamma) = M + \left[ \dfrac{4h}{\pi} \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{x_k\alpha_k+z_k\beta_k} \right] \cdot A \cdot \cos (\omega t+\phi)
$

with 
$
\alpha_k = A_k\cos(\phi_k),\ \beta_k=A_k\sin(\phi_k),\ x_k = \sin(\omega_kt),\ z_k=\cos(\omega_kt)
$ and

$
S = \sum r_i^2
$
with
$
r_i = T_i - f(t_i, \gamma),\
$
where the adjustable parameters are held in the vector $\gamma$.

Is this the right way or should I continue with the first try with the piecewise defined function and how to proceed?

@Choward: You're right, it was an idea how to avoid the piecewise derivative.
Let's rewrite the equation above to the form

$
 T(t) = M + \alpha\cdot x + \beta\cdot z + e\left(t\right)
$

with

$\alpha = A \cdot \cos \left(\phi \right)$, $\beta = -A \cdot \sin \left(\phi \right)$, $x = \cos \left(2 \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{t}{\tau}\right)$ and $z = \sin \left(2 \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{t}{\tau}\right)$.

For all partial derivatives then I would get:

$\dfrac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial M} = 1$ for $c(t) > 0$

$\dfrac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial (A\cos(\phi))} = \cos(\frac{2\pi t}{\tau})$ for $c(t) > 0$

$\dfrac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial (-A\sin(\phi))} = \sin(\frac{2\pi t}{\tau})$ for $c(t) > 0$

and

$\dfrac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial M} = 1$ for $ c(t) < 0$

$\dfrac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial (A\cos(\phi))} = 0$ for $c(t) < 0$

$\dfrac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial (-A\sin(\phi))} = 0$ for $c(t) < 0$

Now I have two sets of equations, one for $c(t) >0$ and $c(t) < 0$. To proceed I continue as following:

$
 \dfrac{\partial S}{\partial \gamma_i} = 2 \cdot \sum{r_i \dfrac{\partial r_i}{\partial \gamma _j}} \ \forall j \\
\rightarrow 0 = -2 \cdot \sum{r_i \dfrac{\partial f(T_i, \gamma)}{\partial \gamma _j}} \ \forall j 
$

and get for $c(t) > 0$

$
0 = -2 \cdot \sum_{i}^{N} \left(T_i - \alpha x_i - \beta z_i \right) \cdot \frac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial M} \\
 \Leftrightarrow\sum_{i}^{N}{T_i}  = M \cdot N + \alpha \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i} + \beta \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{z_i}\\
  0 = -2 \cdot \sum_{i}^{N} \left(T_i - \alpha x_i - \beta z_i \right) \cdot \frac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial \alpha} \\
 \Leftrightarrow\sum_{i}^{N}{T_i\cdot x_i} = M \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i} + \alpha \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i^2} + \beta \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i\cdot z_i} \\
  0 = -2 \cdot \sum_{i}^{N} \left(T_i - \alpha x_i - \beta z_i \right) \cdot \frac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial \beta} \\
 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i}^{N}{T_i\cdot z_i} = M \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{z_i} + \alpha \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i\cdot z_i} + \beta \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{z_i^2}
$

and for $c(t) < 0$

$
0 = -2 \cdot \sum_{i}^{N} \left(T_i - \alpha x_i - \beta z_i \right) \cdot \frac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial M} \\
 \Leftrightarrow\sum_{i}^{N}{T_i}  = M \cdot N + \alpha \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i} + \beta \cdot \sum_{i}^{N}{z_i}\\
  0 = -2 \cdot \sum_{i}^{N} \left(T_i - \alpha x_i - \beta z_i \right) \cdot \frac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial \alpha} \\
 \Leftrightarrow = 0 \\
  0 = -2 \cdot \sum_{i}^{N} \left(T_i - \alpha x_i - \beta z_i \right) \cdot \frac{\partial f(t_i, \gamma)}{\partial \beta} \\
 \Leftrightarrow = 0.
$

For $c(t) > 0$ I can express it using $d = B \cdot u$
$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \sum_{i}^{N}{T_i} \\ \sum_{i}^{N}{T_i\cdot x_i} \\ \sum_{i}^{N}{T_i\cdot z_i}
 \end{pmatrix}
 =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  N & \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i} & \sum_{i}^{N}{z_i} \\
  \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i} & \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i^2} & \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i \cdot z_i} \\
  \sum_{i}^{N}{z_i} & \sum_{i}^{N}{x_i \cdot z_i} & \sum_{i}^{N}{z_i ^2} \\
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \begin{pmatrix}
  M \\ \alpha \\ \beta
 \end{pmatrix}
$

and solve it easily with $u = B^{-1} \cdot d$. For $c(t) < 0$ this does not make sense... How to take this into account?

Comment: What adjustable parameters does $\gamma$ represent in your model?

Comment: In my opinion it would be better to define $T(t) = M + H(c(t))$, where $H(\cdot)$ is a Heaviside step function, and just approximate $H(\cdot)$ using something like the sigmoid function to ensure the derivatives are continuous.

Comment: $\gamma$ contains $M$, $A\cos(\phi)$ and $-A\sin(\phi)$

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you considered the Fourier series?  It actually seems fairly simple to compute $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ as a piecewise function of $t$:

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{\partial c}{\partial t} & c(t) > 0 \\ 0 & c(t) < 0 \end{matrix} \right. = \left\{ \begin{matrix} -\frac{2\pi}{\tau} A \sin( \frac{2\pi}{\tau} t + \phi) & c(t) > 0 \\ 0 & c(t) < 0 \end{matrix} \right.$$

So, from here, you just need to figure out the values of $t$ for which $c(t)$ is positive/negative.

(Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question?)

Comment: The OP used the Fourier series to avoid having a piecewise derivative so, I assume, the optimization problem is smooth.